# Markov chains and conditioning on impossible events

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain $(X_0,X_1,\ldots)$ with a state space $S\equiv\{s_1,s_2\}$ and the following matrix of “transition probabilities” (I will explain the use of quotation marks below):
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&s_1&s_2\\
\hline
s_1&1&0\\
s_2&1&0
\end{array}
\end{align*}
That is, no matter what initial state the system starts in, it will always end up in state $s_1$ in one period and stay there forever.

---

Rigorously speaking, these “transition probabilities” are to be interpreted as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\,(X_{n}=s_1\,|\,X_{n-1}=s_1)=&\,1,\\
\mathbb P\,(X_{n}=s_2\,|\,X_{n-1}=s_1)=&\,0,\\
\mathbb P\,(X_{n}=s_1\,|\,X_{n-1}=s_2)=&\,1,\\
\mathbb P\,(X_{n}=s_2\,|\,X_{n-1}=s_2)=&\,0
\end{align*}
for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

---

My concern is that the last two probabilities are ill-defined (except possibly for $n=1$), because for any given initial probabilities, the condition events $\{X_{n-1}=s_2\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ have zero probability! Strictly speaking, therefore, the above matrix cannot be interpreted as conditional probabilities because of the problem of conditioning on events that never occur.

---

What is the standard resolution of this technical problem? Does one make the hand-waving assumption of defining conditional probabilities that depend on impossible events anyway, or is there a more sophisticated and rigorous way around this issue?

---

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact one  defines the transition kernels:
$$K(\omega, j) = \Bbb{E}(1_{X_n = j} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1})(\omega) \quad \Bbb{P } \,a.s. $$

This means that we have a regular conditional probability that allows us to talk about the jumps of our process.

The markov property consists in saying that $K(\cdot, j)$ is $\sigma(X_{n-1})$ measurable

that is

$$K(\omega, j) = \phi_j(X_{n-1})(\omega) \quad \Bbb{P}\, a.s.  $$

Hence there is no hand waving.

Comment: I see, thank you. So basically a rigorous way of operationalizing conditioning on null events is to regard the conditional probabilities $$\mathbb P\,(X_n=j\,|\,\sigma(X_0,\ldots X_{n-1}))$$ as being defined _up to almost-everywhere equivalence_ (with respect to the unconditional probability measure $\mathbb P$) and impose the Markov property as the equivalence classes of $$\mathbb P\,(X_n=j\,|\,\sigma(X_0,\ldots X_{n-1}))$$ and $$\mathbb P\,(X_n=j\,|\,\sigma(X_{n-1}))$$ being identical. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, there is no guarantee that each of the states
in a Markov Chain can be visited at any particular step $n$.
Another good example with lots of impossible visits is a periodic
chain where any one state can only be visited on every $d$th step,
where $d$ is the period.

More subtle are examples on countably infinite state spaces.
For example, consider a random walk on the non-negative integers
with a 'drift' towards 0 and a reflecting barrier at 0. The
higher-numbered states may be visited extremely rarely.

Some texts do not address the interpretation of conditional
probability for conditions with probability 0 at all. Others
agree to ignore the conditional probability in cases where
it is moot. Yet others, instead of your "for all $n$" seem
to say "for all applicable $n$." In any case, this issue is not
a difficulty in applications.